# LibreOffice impress - turn off toolbar auto hides upon activating images

Tags: libreoffice

I use LibreOffice 5.0.2.2 in Ubuntu 14.04. I want to turn off the autohide feature of "line and style bar" upon the activation of images.

When I use Impress to make slides, upon clicking on images, the "line and filling bar" automatically disappears (irrespective of being locked or not) . This has two annoying consequences:

1. it causes the GUI to flinch;
2. the image is unintentionally moved downwards since the whole slide moves upwards as the slide auto-adjusts itself to the center of the GUI ( "line and filling bar" disappears, space is larger).

When the image is deactivated, the bar appears again.

I failed to turn this behavior off (toolbar customize, options, google, etc). Does anyone happen to know how to do that? TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some googling and reading, I realize this is a context-sensitive toolbar and it is not possible to disable its auto-hide behavior. The simple trick to prevent the flinch is to insert a **customized dummy toolbar**, which by default is context-insensitive, before the "line and filling" in the same row. This way, even if the "line and filling" toolbar disappears upon clicking a picture in the slide, the GUI won't flinch as the customized toolbar works as a **placeholder**. Furthermore, you can add tools you need to your customized toolbar so you still have access to them even if the "line and filling" is gone.